# Number of Redis queries

Tags: redis

I have a script that runs 12-16 redis commands;

This might look like a dumb question but, considering that this script is usually called every couple of seconds, are they maybe too much to be executed all at once? I mean is Redis also designed to have such number of commands or should it be kept really as minimal as possible?

I am basically using LISTS for queues, SETS and strings.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So basically your script averages 6-8 redis queries per second? How many of those scripts are running in parallel and approximately how much data are you getting from redis for each call?

Comment: It's 12-16. Right now I am getting 0 parallels but I am expecting around 1000 concurrently. The data I am getting is basically just IDs so not too long string.

Comment: According to [this](http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks), a single Redis server should to about 100k queries per second over Gigabit ethernet at reasonably small data sizes. Your application should be comfortably under that limit, but you should read the linked page to see that you're not hitting any other limits (network speed/server being a VM etc)

Comment: aha, I am terrible with math, how many queries am I getting currently? got an idea?

Comment: Currently, 12-16 queries per 2 (couple of) seconds would make 6-8 per second. 1000 parallels of those would mean 6000-8000 queries/second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the numbers you posted there are no problems at all, Redis can handle this traffic without any issue unless those queries are intersections of big sets, or SORT, or other commands that have a run time proportional to number of elements in your type.

However it is not just a matter of Redis able to handle the traffic, you should also be concerned about latency. If you use pipelining (http://redis.io/topics/pipelining) you can ask multiple queries at once and avoid paying the round trip time multiple times.

Comment: yes. I'm obviously using pipelining for this. Salvatore! I'm a great fan of you, and I'm from Catania! Have you got any open positions at kiurma for a junior dev. by any chance?